# center crop not cropping photo in relativelayout

Tags: android

I want to center crop an image but its not doing anything just stretching my photo - can someone please help.

Thanks in advance

```
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/Photos"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/background_image"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/girl"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your image view to this

```
   <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/background_image"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/girl"
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"  />
```

Comment: this creates a spacing on the side of the image and still stretches the image

Comment: Edited answer should work. It will center crop the image in the available region

Comment: This also doesn't work - it just stretches my image. it doesn't crop it

Comment: strange. Let me try it for you

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** *after testing* .. you should specify the 'layout_width' and the 'layout_height' inside 'FrameLayout'.

for example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/girl"
    android:scaleType="center"> //
</ImageView>
</FrameLayout>
```